# How to mute/unmute Video using Exoplayer control view with Imagebutton icon

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer, android-design-library

Hi Im developing one video application
Here I am using exoplayerview for playing video.In this videoview Im using exoplayer control view.In this control I change custom icon such as Mute/Unmute Icon.while Im clicking the icon the coontrol view is getting hide.But not able to mute or unmute the video.Can you Please help how to fix this problems..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope you're doing good, here is a snippet you can use to achieve what you want to do

```
fun setTwoStateVolume(mute : Boolean) {
        player?.volume = if (mute) 0F else 1F
}
```

so call this function inside your "mute" and "unmute" button listener
where player here is an instance of `SimpleExoPlayer`

for more info checkout this [link](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/5327).